# Cloud Composer meta-database keeps increasing even with cleanup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running a Cloud Composer environment on GCP.

I see that the meta-database size keeps increasing.

I have followed the documentation's instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/cleanup-airflow-database

and added the recommended cleanup DAG with 10 days retention period, but still over time it keeps increasing.

What am I missing?